# How to get BYTE from bytea?

Tags: c, postgresql, types

In the extension for postgresql, I encrypt `char*`, get a `BYTE` buffer, write it to a file, and return it as `bytea*` via `PG_RETURN_BYTEA_P`. When I try to read the same through `bytea* b = PG_GETARG_BYTEA_P`, the read does not match what I wrote to the file. How to read `bytea` correctly to get `BYTE` and decrypt again? Everything is in C.

Part of code:

```
FILE* log = AllocateFile("C:\\pg\\log.txt", PG_BINARY_A);

    //get data to decrypt
    bytea* dataToDecrypt = PG_GETARG_BYTEA_P(0);
    FILE* tempFile = AllocateFile("C:\\pg\\file1.txt", PG_BINARY_A);
    fwrite(dataToDecrypt, sizeof(dataToDecrypt), 1, tempFile);
    FreeFile(tempFile);
```

I put the data in a `file1` to use an example from Microsoft. Further everything as in the example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/example-c-program-decrypting-a-file
In the end:

```
FreeFile(log);
PG_RETURN_BYTEA_P(pbBuffer);
```